# How to add specific files in gitignore?

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I have added some files in the same directory of .gitignore. When I push the changes to BitBucket, the files added in .gitignore, also uploaded.
How to ignore babel.config.json and package.lock.json. Refer the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Those are two files you _shouldn't_ ignore, but also once a file is tracked you have to explicitly remove it not just ignore further changes.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the files to the .gitignore file, you have to delete them locally.

*(assuming you've already pushed .gitignore to your repo)*

Comment: I see `jonrsharpe` was just a few seconds earlier.